# Python copy files to folder

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to copy files from one folder to another (without knowing the names of the files)

However, it's not working and I can't seem to understand why. Below is the code and the error code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, time, shutil

path = '/home/images/'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
        src = path+f
        dst = '/USB/images/' +f
        shutil.move(src, dst)
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.move(dst, src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/USB/images/26-07-2015-18:06:22-01.jpg'
```

Can anybody help me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: You could try use the copyfile function from the shutil module maybe it will work

Comment: Try printing the strings `src` and `dst` to see if they are actually what you need them to be.

Comment: I did, and they come out exactly like I want them.

Comment: should it not be something like   `'/home/images/USB/images/'+f`? where exactly is `USB/images`?

Comment: What filesystem is on `/USB`? If it's FAT (or derivative), you may not be allowed to use `:` characters in filenames.

Comment: You're absolutly right Daniel, thanks.

Comment: The stack trace says it should be dst, src.

Answer (score 2):

The code and error message don't appear to tally up to one another.

The code suggests you're calling

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

but the error suggests you're calling

```
shutil.move(dst, src)
```

If you're doing the latter then clearly the error message makes sense if the `/USB/images/26-07-2015-18:06:22-01.jpg` does not already exist.

You may also have trouble using `:` characters in the filenames. The FAT (or derivative) filesystem is common on (typically smaller) USB devices. That filesystem type does not permit any of the following characters in filenames: `"/\*?<>|:`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
shutil.move(dst, src)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your destination dir is not writable, or non-existent?
What do you see when you do `ls -l /USB/images`?

BTW, I thought you wanted to copy? shutil.move will move the file, not copy.

**EDIT: destination VFAT requires special file conversion**

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, time, shutil

path = '/home/images/'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    f_dst = f.replace(':','_')
    src os.path.join(path, f)
    dst = os.path.join('/USB/images/', f_dst)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: pi@raspi /USB $ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 8192 Jul 26 17:30 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 8192 Jul 26 18:00 videos
I can see the files/folders and write/read them.

Comment: @Rishav - I can't comment yet, see my rep?

Comment: @Kagetaze - what happens when you copy/move files manually using shell 'mv' or 'cp'? This error is definitely because destination is not writable either because of permission or it's non-existent.

Also if this is a separate filesystem mounted from USB or something (as the name alludes to), you need to ensure it's mounted read-write.

Comment: That's odd. It comes back as:
pi@raspi ~/images $ cp /home/images/26-07-2015-18:06:22-01.jpg /USB/images/26-07-2015-18:06:22-01.jpg
cp: cannot create regular file `/USB/images/26-07-2015-18:06:22-01.jpg': Invalid argument
  What does this mean?

Comment: Usually that means it's not mounted with read-write permission. What does 'mount | grep USB' show? Can you even touch/create a file in /USB/images?

I also saw Padraic's similar comment above.

Comment: /dev/sda1 on /USB type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

I can create files on it, yes. Fairly sure it's mounted..

Comment: Ah.. it's VFAT filesystem. I think then you need to convert your filenames. I don't think it takes ':' as filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Use the OS-agnostic function [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to effectively concatenate file names to folder paths.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, time, shutil

path = '/home/images/'

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
  src = os.path.join(path, f)
  dst = os.path.join('/USB/images/', f)
  shutil.move(src, dst)
```